# Problems getting jquery datatables to sort special date input fields with moment

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a page using jQuery Datatables 1.10.5. The table works fine but I have a date in this format 'D-M-YY' eg.g. 10-03-15, (10th March 2015).

I have included this in the head so I am loading moment.js.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
```

And I call this to initialize the table:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'D-M-YY' );
$('.datatable').DataTable({....options here, language etc..
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong since the column will not sort on my date. I have read all the docs a datatable.net but it seems I am calling it correctly.

*** UPDATE
I am able to use this plugin and it sorts input fields.
http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/custom-data-source/dom-text

Still I can only sort by UNIX date like yyyy-mm-dd. I want to sort by custom date dd-mm-yy. I use this to initialize the input field:

/* Create an array with the values of all the input boxes in a column*/

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-text-numeric'] = function ( settings, col ) 
{return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) 
{ return $('input', td).val() * 1; } ); }
```

Then I define the date field no. 3

```
$('#example').dataTable( { "columns": [ null, null, { "orderDataType":"dom-text", type: 'text' } ] } );
```

I even tried this:

```
{ "orderDataType":"dom-text", type: 'date' }
```

Is there a valid value "dom-date" ?

Comment: Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bqL2exsg/

Comment: I think I have progress. Working on this plugin now
https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html

Comment: Have you solved this,  sorting columns by the input value?

Comment: No sorry, no solution.  I had to give up on sorting for that date field until I find this out.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar situation before where I want to display different information than I want the column sorted on.  Here's what I ended up with:

- Column 1: Display the date in whatever format you want
- Column 2: Use the date parts to put together a correctly sortable string, and hide this column

Then, use the following for the `columnDefs` definition:

```
'columnDefs': [
    { 'orderData':[1], 'targets': [0] },
    {
        'targets': [1],
        'visible': false,
        'searchable': false
    },
],
```

This is saying: when you sort on the first column, use the second columns value to do the sorting.